# Android View Display Z Ordering

Tags: android, android-view

Im very new to android development..

It looks like the ImageView is ontop of the VideoView, and therefore the VideoView does not display. Is this true? And do I need to change the order of the views when I want to videoview to show? and again when the imageView must display an image?

*I loop through a list of images and videos and show the images for x seconds, then move on to the next element, could be a video or image.*

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@raw/image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />  
    <VideoView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/videoView" />

<!--     <SurfaceView 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/surface" />    -->


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Z-ordering that's your problem. You have a `LinearLayout` with two views. It's set to `horizontal`, so it wants to draw them next to each other. However, you are using `fill_parent` for the width, so the first view takes up all the space, and the next view is drawn off the screen(to the right).

A simple solution would be to flip the `visibility` states of the views when you want one or the other shown. There are more elegant ways to do this, I'm sure, but that's a simple one.

Comment: Do you mean like this: View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE). ?

Comment: Yes, just like that. You'll just have to keep track of which is `VISIBLE` and which is `GONE`. I wouldn't recommend `INVISIBLE` for this, since it will still occupy its layout space when `INVISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

as the imageView and the videoView are in the same LinearLayout, they display next to each other; not on another layer.

I guess the VideoView is not showing as you don't link any content to it. At least that is what my eclipse is displaying.